# Can't upload files to s3 with Flutter amplify

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

Whenever I try to upload an image to my s3 bucket created in flutter nothing happens.

```
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    try{
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
        
        
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
    print("here");
    final key = new DateTime.now().toString();
    print(key);
    Map<String, String> metadata = <String, String>{};
metadata['name'] = 'filename';
metadata['desc'] = 'A test file';
S3UploadFileOptions options = S3UploadFileOptions(accessLevel: StorageAccessLevel.private, metadata: metadata);
try {
  UploadFileResult result = await Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
    key: key,
    local: _image,
    options: options
  );
  print("Uploaded");
} on StorageException catch (e) {
  print(e.message);
}
}catch (e){
      Alert(
          context: context,
          type: AlertType.error,
          desc: "Error Uploading File: " + e.toString());
    }

  }
```

I I've found this discussion on the topic https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/discussions/550 however I don't have a amplifyconfiguration.json file I have it in .dart form. Also all of my information is present. I'm not sure why I'm not able to upload to s3. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you push your amplify backend? Does the bucket exist in S3? For amplify-flutter .dart file will be there, this is fine.

Comment: Look at your _imag=File(pickedFile.path) - you didn't actually open the file. You just got the reference to it. Check here how to read a file: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File-class.html

Comment: @Andrija Yes the bucket exist and I did push the backend. I'm also using the image picker library and the way you get this image is pass the path then with that you should be able to upload the file https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker.

Answer (score 0):

```
final pickedFile =
    await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

if (pickedFile != null) {
  var imagePath = pickedFile.path;
  var nameWithExtension = imagePath.split('/')[6];
  var imageName = nameWithExtension.split('.')[0];
}

use imagePath in local
```